# How to show an image in a QLabel

Tags: c++, image, qt, plugins

I'm trying to show an image from a resource file in a **QLabel**. All this is happenning from a plugin that extends the main core application.

```
#include "sampleplugin.h"
#include <QtWidgets>

SamplePlugin :: SamplePlugin()
{

    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(pluginresources);

    oLContainerWidget = new QWidget();

    olWrapper = new QHBoxLayout();
    bagIcon(":/sample_plugin_resources/images/Dry-50.png");

    oLContainerWidget -> setLayout(olWrapper);
}

void SamplePlugin :: testIcon(const QString &imageUrl)
{
    QPixmap pix(imageUrl);

    QLabel *sampleIconLabel = new QLabel();
    sampleIconLabel -> setPixmap(pix);

    olWrapper -> addWidget(sampleIconLabel);
}
```

The project compiles without any errors, but the image doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

The project structure:

```
**plugins_dir**  
    sampleplugin  
        pluginresources.qrc  
        sample_plugin_resources  
            - Dry-50.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Check that `pix` has actually loaded the image (`pix.isNull()`). You are loading the image from a resource path, is that the complete path on your QRC file?

Comment: Could you solve the problem? Anything else to try to figure it out?